# How to use Delegate actions as a parameter?

Tags: c#

I Used a delegate action as a parameter in a method as follows:

```
private IEnumerable<SC.ServerPathServices.GAFPFileInfo> StartProjectArchive(Int32 projectID, Int32 sourceServerPathID, Action uiRefresh,Action<IEnumerable<ProjectFile>> PopUpFiles)
```

Here I have two delegates. I have a problem with PopUpFiles Delegate.

I am calling this in my method by passing list of files as a parameter to PopUpFiles As follows:

```
 if(PopUpFiles!=null)
                   PopUpFiles(filesModifiedInSourceServer);
```

Here filesModifiedInSourceServer contains list of files.
I am calling this in a code behind file as follows:

```
archiveResponse = projectManager.StartProjectArchive(projectId, 0, () =>
                     {
                         foreach (Control control in tdFileList.Controls.Cast<Control>())
                         {
                             if (control is Dell.AFP.UserControl.ProjectFileListBaseControl)
                             {
                                 ((ProjectFileListBaseControl)control).Refresh();
                             }
                         }
                     },
                     (filesModifiedInSourceServer)=>
                         {
                             if (filesModifiedInSourceServer != null && filesModifiedInSourceServer.Count > 0)
                             {
                             PopUpModifiedFiles(filesModifiedInSourceServer);
                             }
                         });
```

But in the above code when I am passing parameter for the delegate action PopUpFiles I used filesModifiedInSourceServer as a parameter. It is giving me an error as delegate action does not take one argument. How else I can pass the parameter?
this is resolved. Now I am getting object reference error while calling that method. I do not know why it is throwing object reference error.

Comment: What line is the error?

Comment: while passing parameters to that action. Here is the code (filesModifiedInSourceServer)=> here only I am getting that error

Comment: I dont see anything obviously wrong with the syntax (but then again, I am still only on my first cup of coffee ;p). Edit: What is the signature of `PopUpModifiedFiles`? Also `filesModifiedInSourceServer.Count` is not right, should be `.Count()` given that it is `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: That error? What's the error message?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)